# Define class in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I want to test an inclusion of a module into a class. I am trying define a new class in RSpec:

```
describe Statusable do
  let(:test_class) do
    class ModelIncludingStatusable < ActiveRecord::Base
      include Statusable
      statuses published: "опубликовано", draft: "черновик"
    end
  end

  describe '#statuses' do
    it 'sets STATUSES for a model' do
      test_class::STATUSES.should == ["опубликовано", "черновик"]
    end
  end
end
```

And I get an error:

```
TypeError:
       [ActiveModel::Validations::InclusionValidator] is not a class/module
```

This is probably because in `Statusable` I have:

```
validates_inclusion_of  :status, :in => statuses,
            :message => "{{value}} должен быть одним из: #{statuses.join ','}"
```

But if I comment it out, I get:

```
TypeError:
       ["опубликовано", "черновик"] is not a class/module
```

Maybe new class definition isn't the best option, what do I do then? And even if it's not, how can I define a class in RSpec? And how do I fix this error?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Do not define new constant in tests otherwise it will pollute other tests. Instead, use `stub_const`.

Also, for this is an unit test of Statusable module. If ActiveRecord model is not a necessity, better not to use it.

You can also use `class_eval` to avoid not opening this class(no matter fake or not) actually

```
describe Statusable do
  before do
    stub_const 'Foo', Class.new
    Foo.class_eval{ include Statusable }
    Foo.class_eval{ statuses published: "foo", draft: "bar"}
  end

  context '#statuses' do
    it 'sets STATUSES for a model' do
      FOO::STATUSES.should == ["foo", "bar"]
    end
  end
end
```

Though I copied your assertion, I would suggest not to insert a constant say `STATUS` into the class/module(Foo) who includes this module. Instead, a class method would be better

```
expect(Foo.status).to eq(["foo", "bar"])
```

Comment: @leemour, my pleasure. Two reasons for class method: 1. the constant name should be static. In question, "STATUS" is actually under namespace "Foo" to read as "Statusable::STATUS", but now it is "FOO::STATUS" which intends to mean same thing. 2. The constant value should be static, you can't expect the value of constant to change as per the code.

Comment: Good point, but I was defining STATUS dynamically in `#statuses`, when it's called in class that included `Statusable` like in my code above. Bad decision?

Comment: @leemour, constant should not be dynamic. You can use class method for dynamic things.

Comment: I like the fact that constants are unchangeable. I am defining it dynamically but doing it only once. Is defining constant once and protecting it from overwriting (I am checking for it) a bad practice?

Answer (score 2):

It fails because class definition does not return itself.

```
$ irb
> class Foo; 1 end
 => 1
```

you need to do like this:

```
  let(:test_class) do
    class ModelIncludingStatusable < ActiveRecord::Base
      include Statusable
      statuses published: "опубликовано", draft: "черновик"
    end
    ModelIncludingStatusable # return the class
  end
```

It works but unfortunately, `ModelIncludingStatusable` will be defined on top-level because of ruby rule.

To capsulize your class, you should do like this:

```
  class self::ModelIncludingStatusable < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Statusable
    statuses published: "опубликовано", draft: "черновик"
  end
  let(:test_class) do
    self.class::ModelIncludingStatusable # return the class
  end
```

It works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `let` this define a memoized helper method. You can't  `class` definition in method body.

Answer (score 0):

Another option which I frequently use is to put the entire test in it's own module, e.g.

```
module Mapping::ModelSpec
  module Human
    Person = Struct.new(:name, :age, :posessions)
    Possession = Struct.new(:name, :value)
  end

  RSpec.describe Mapping::Model do
    it 'can map with base class' do
      person = Human::Person.new('Bob Jones', 200, [])

      ...
    end
  end
end
```

While this is a bit cumbersome, it avoids polluting the global namespace, is only slightly more syntax, and is generally easy to understand. Personally, I'd like a better option.. but I'm not sure what that would be.